# How to retrieve data from multiple tables using EF 5 linq method

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I am facing a problem as discussed below.

I have four tables

- `PateintTable`
- `PatientRecordTable(FK=PatientID)`
- `RecordMedicineTable(FK=MedicineID,RecordID)`
- `MedicineTable`

I want to get a specific Patient data depending upon the PatientID of the patient along with the patient data, I want to obtain his medical-records (PatientRecordTable) plus medicines associated with each of his records.

I tried many tricks but exceptions occur when I try to get the medicines.

```
 lstPrescribedMedicines.Items.Clear();
     foreach (var item in result.RecordsMedicines)
     {
          lstPrescribedMedicines.Items.Add(item.Medicine.MedName);
     }
```

I am implementing `using(context=new mss-context())`.
This is my query:

```
var pateintRecords = context
          .PateintRecords
          .Include(p => p.Patient)
          .Include(m=>m.RecordsMedicines)
          .Where(x => x.PatientID == pateintID).ToList();// as IQueryable;
```

[image]

Comment: what's the exception you are getting?

Comment: when i try to get the medicines, it throws an exception that the context is no longer available.  lstPrescribedMedicines.Items.Clear();
        foreach (var item in result.RecordsMedicines)
        {
        lstPrescribedMedicines.Items.Add(item.Medicine.MedName);
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with children of children, you have to include them:

```
var pateintRecords = context
          .PateintRecords
          .Include(p => p.Patient)
          .Include(m=>m.RecordsMedicines)
          .Include(m=>m.RecordsMedicines.Select(i => i.Items))
          .Where(x => x.PatientID == pateintID).ToList();// as IQueryable;
```